# Capture ffmpeg's metadata output in powershell

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I'm trying to capture the output of `ffmpeg` in PowerShell(tm) to get some metadata on some ogg & mp3 files. But when I do:

```
ffmpeg -i file.ogg 2>&1 | sls GENRE
```

The output includes a bunch of lines without my matching string, "GENRE":

```
      album_artist    : Post Human Era
      ARTIST          : Post Human Era
      COMMENT         : Visit http://posthumanera.bandcamp.com
      DATE            : 2013
      GENRE           : Music
      TITLE           : Supplies
      track           : 1
At least one output file must be specified
```

I am guessing something is different in the encoding. ffmpeg's output is colored, so maybe there are color control characters in the output that are breaking things? Or, maybe ffmpeg's output isn't playing nicely with powershell's default UTF-16? I can't figure out if there is another way to redirect stderr and remove the color characters or change the encoding of stderr.

EDIT:
Strangely, I also get indeterminate output. Sometimes the output is as shown above. Sometimes with precisely the same command the output is:

```
      GENRE           :
```

[image]

Which makes slightly more sense, but is still missing the part of the line I care about ('Music').

Somewhere powershell is interpreting something as newlines that is not newlines.

Comment: `sls` or `Select-String` is returning a match object. If those all appear in the same string the entire string is returned. Also you are just matching GENRE alone so if you were to expand just the matched data you would end up with GENRE as that is your query.

Comment: Yes, but why is that entire block count as a single match when it is multiple lines? Wouldn't that indicate an encoding/control character issue? Otherwise `sls` would receive each line individually...

Comment: Edited with more info

Comment: What is the result of this `(ffmpeg -i file.ogg 2>&1).GetType().FullName`

Comment: `System.Object[]`?

Comment: Ok. So it did return an array then.

Comment: Yes. `System.Object[]`. And there are weird splits. For example `(ffmpeg -i file.ogg 2>&1)[53]` sometimes returns `Musi`, sometimes `c`, sometimes an empty(?) string, sometimes `Supplies`, and sometimes `      TITLE           : `.  The splits are in odd places as well as changing unpredictably.

Comment: That is why your `select-string` is not returning the results you expect. Start with this `ffmpeg -i file.ogg 2>&1 | Out-String`. That will make it one string.

Comment: A string can treated as a char array so be careful with that. Check the `.Count` to be sure how many elements there are

Comment: That retains the splits. I know splitting is causing the issue. I just need to know why and how to prevent the splitting.

Comment: I'm going through the same struggle right now. the command itself is returning consistent values, but as soon as I use `2>&1`, it returns a different, incomplete variation each time. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I don't quite remember, but I think I eventually gave up. Sorry.

Comment: @Mica - 3 years later - yes. See my solution below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still seeing this behavior when I use the old powershell, but I have since upgraded to PowerShell Core (7.0.2), and the problem seems to be solved. I read somewhere that with PowerShell Core they've changed the default encoding to UTF-8, so perhaps it is something related to that.

[image]

My theory is that in the old version, whatever code combines the outputstreams normally would make sure that individual lines were preserved and interleaved instead of of cut up. But I would guess that this code is looking for newlines in the default encoding, not UTF-8, so when it receives two UTF-8 streams it doesn't parse the line delimiters correctly and you get weird splits. It seems like there should be a way to change the encoding before it gets to mixing the output streams, but I'm not sure (and now it doesn't matter since it works). Why the output seems to change nondeterministically, I don't know, unless there is something nondeterministic about parsing UTF8 bytes as if they were UTF16 or whatever the default is.

Comment: & "$folderpath\ffmpeg.exe" -i $path 2>&1 | ForEach {

Answer (score 0):

I got something working for my script catching all the output with regex and pipe to a custom object

```
Function Rotate-Video {
param(
[STRING]$FFMPEGEXE = "P:\Video Editing\ffmpeg-4.3.1-2020-10-01-full_build\bin\ffmpeg.exe",
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
[STRING]$Source      = "D:\Video\Source",
[STRING]$Destination = 'D:\Video\Destination',
[STRING]$DestinationExtention='mp4'
)

    (Get-ChildItem $Source) | ForEach-Object {
        $FileExist  = $false
        $Source     = $_.fullname
        $Name       = $_.basename
        $outputName = $name+'.'+$DestinationExtention
        $Fullpath   = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath $outputName
        $Regex      = "(\w+)=\s+(\d+)\s+(\w+)=(\d+.\d+)\s+(\w)=(\d+.\d+)\s+(\w+)=\s+(\d+)\w+\s+(\w+)=(\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+)\s+(\w+)=(\d+.\d+)\w+\/s\s+(\w+)=(\d+.\d+)"
        &$FFMPEGEXE -i $Source -vf transpose=clock $Fullpath 2>&1 | Select-String -Pattern $Regex  | ForEach-Object {       
            $output = ($_ | Select-String -Pattern $regex).Matches.Groups
            [PSCUSTOMOBJECT]@{
                Source      = $source
                Destination = $Fullpath
                $output[1]  = $output[2]
                $output[3]  = $output[4]
                $output[5]  = $output[6]
                $output[7]  = $output[8]
                $output[9]  = $output[10]
                $output[11] = $output[12]
                $output[13] = $output[14]
            }
        }
    }
}
```